# Getting Error while running thread on a overloaded functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, compiler-errors, overloading

```
static bool breakThread= false;

void TestMeUsingMiltiThreading(unsigned int uParentID)
{
    std::cout << "Thread " << uParentID << " Invoked Current thread " << std::this_thread::get_id();
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    while (!breakThread)
    {
        std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " is working..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);//Thread wait for 1s before contuning further
    }
}
void TestMeUsingMiltiThreading()
{
    std::cout << "Current thread id is=" << std::this_thread::get_id();
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    while (!breakThread)
    {
        std::cout << "Thread "<< std::this_thread::get_id() <<" is working..."<< std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);//Thread wait for 1s before contuning further
    }
}

.
.
.
int main()
{
.
.
.
std::thread worder(TestMeUsingMiltiThreading); //error here
.
.
.
}
```

Error:
E0289   no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list

How to fix this, I want to run threads over overloaded functions

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using btw? The newer versions can't be used to build in C++11 mode. It's C++14 or later for those.

Comment: I am Using VS 2022

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell it which overload you want since it can't deduce which function you want a function pointer to. It must be able to form a pointer to the proper `TestMeUsingMiltiThreading` even before you supply it to `std::thread`. Compare it with doing this:

```cpp
auto func_ptr = TestMeUsingMiltiThreading; // error
```

It can't know which one you want here either.

One way to solve it is to do a `static_cast<void(*)()>` which makes it pick the only overload for which that cast works:

```cpp
std::thread worder(static_cast<void(*)()>(TestMeUsingMiltiThreading));
```

Or using an intermediate variable to do it:

```cpp
auto func_ptr = static_cast<void(*)()>(TestMeUsingMiltiThreading); // now ok
// or
//void(*func_ptr)() = TestMeUsingMiltiThreading;
std::thread worder(func_ptr);
```

Similarly, if you'd like to use the other overload:

```cpp
std::thread worder(static_cast<void(*)(unsigned)>(TestMeUsingMiltiThreading), 1u);
```

---

Sidenote: `breakThread` should be a `std::atomic<bool>` since you are not synchronizing the reads from it with the writes to it.